# How to cythonize a Python-ROS2 package in order to hide the source code?

Tags: python, cython, cythonize, ros2

I have a ROS2-python (rclpy) package with multiple subpackages that work together. I would like to cythonize the package in order to hide the source code and just leave the executables to do the job. Any idea how could I do that with the setup.py of the package and the launch files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would answer my own question in case someone faced the same issue. For cythonizing your ros2 package in python the best way is adding the required cython components to the **setup.py** of each package separately. I have marked the cython parts (with <--) for a better understranding.

Please note that after building the package using colcon, a copy of the python source codes would be stored under the install directory produced by colcon. You can easily delete them manually and the package should run with the generated c and shared object files.

```
from glob import glob
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize <--
import os

package_name = 'your_package_name_here'

files = package_name + "/*.py"

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(files,compiler_directives={'language_level' : "3"},force=True,quiet=True), <--
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=[package_name],
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
            ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
        (os.path.join('share', package_name), glob('launch/*.launch.py'))
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools', "wheel",  "Cython"], <--
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='NAME',
    maintainer_email='EMAIL',
    description='TODO: Package description',
    license='TODO: License declaration',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'SOME CODE HERE',
        ],
    },
)
```

Comment: I have similar case to yours, after compilation I found the problem with logging in ROS2 node caused changing logger severity, have you ever encountered similar errors?

Comment: I cannot remember seeing an error like this. Can you maybe give some more details or post the whole error?

Comment: Here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77287788/cannot-log-in-ros2-node-after-building-with-cython