# How to create only cythonize file in ROS2 Python package?

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, ros2, cythonize

I recently followed the instructions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72168194/how-to-cythonize-a-python-ros2-package-in-order-to-hide-the-source-code) to cythonize my ROS2 Python package. The process was successful, and my package is functioning correctly. 
However, I'm curious if there is a way to configure the `setup.py` specifically for building only the cython file, eliminating the need to manually delete the original Python file in order to hide the source code.